# How do you build replaceable DLLs with visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, compatibility

I'd like to build certain extensions of my game into a DLL so that I can recompile the extensions and replace the DLL without rebuilding the entire game. How do I go about doing that?

I read somewhere that each new version of the DLL would have to be "binary compatible" with the old one. Are DLLs compiled with visual studio binary compatible by default as long as I don't change the function names?

Comment: If the code that uses your DLL was compiled with the same version of Visual Studio then yes.

Comment: And also using same .net framework. Those dll's which are compiled in 3.5 version of .netFW will not work with application compiled in 2.0 version of .netFW

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: are there settings in VS, or any other compiler that allow you to compile backward compatible DLLs? I haven't been able to find any documentation on this issue.

Comment: You can install Visual Studio 2008 and 2005 and you can use the VS 2008 or 2005 compiler that gets installed from Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: awesome, thanks. Can you repost as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @Nick have you thought of extending your game via dynamic scripting like using lua, ruby or python? Then you can sidestep the issue of compiling the DLL altogether.

Comment: yes, but I haven't had any experience with any of those languages yet, so it seemed easier to me just to create a basic virtual base class of a script and override it's methods.

Comment: [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) is one way Microsoft went about trying to solve the various ABI issues.  It also allows you to call your DLL from other languages, or across machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you export classes from your DLL you will break the compatibility if you change a version of compiler. In order to solve this problem do this.

Make class interfaces like :

```
class EXPORT_IMPORT_MACROS IMyApi{
public:
 virtual void doSomething( IOtherApi* api ) = 0;
 virtual void doSomething2( IOtherApi2* api ) = 0;
};
```

and export them from your dll. It will give you a header files which are independent from dll implementation and also exportable that means that it will not generate any problem with different versions of runtime library. Also you could take a look to COM technology.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do more than just keep the function names the same. What you have to ensure is called Application Binary Interface, or ABI, compatibility.

There's lots of stuff this entails beyond just symbol names. For example, you have do things like to keep data structures that are passed across the DLL boundary the same size, and the compiler has to place any class members defined in your module but accessed outside of it in the same relative location. A lot of it is up to the compiler's ABI. Microsoft compilers have a bad habit of not being ABI compatible across versions, while some other compilers work a little harder at being compatible. But remember that it requires more than just using the same compiler.

You'll probably need to read up on maintaining ABI compatibility in your environment because it probably involves more details than could be listed here and there are lots of ways to go wrong. Here's [one short article](http://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++) on it. There may be better ones specifically for MSVC compilers.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is recompiling the DLLs. The DLLs are compatible provided that the version of compiler (Visual Studio) doesn't change. Otherwise you will have to check the manual for compatibility between Visual Studio versions.

Another way of doing this is by loading the dll dynamically by using [LoadLibrary function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and after that using [GetProcAddress function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the address of the function you want to call.

If you use the latter you can use any compiler as long as you [export the functions correctly using dllexport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and import them with dllimport. More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h658af8%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).